# Why do some tiles have red "chips" on them in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5 some of the hexes have a little red splotch on them, especially during the early game.

I've been going under the assumption that these signify strategic resources that I don't know how to use yet - they might be handy later once I discover Oil or whatever.

Is this remotely correct?

Comment: I know exactly what you're talking about - I see those too, and the patches haven't fixed them for me yet. I'm assuming graphical glitch, but you never know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a graphics bug. It was supposedly fixed during the october patch -- have you installed it? Specifically:

> Map – Terrain caching fix that could
>   cause problems for certain video cards
>   (the "glowing red orbs" seen on the
>   map are an indicator of this).

Comment: In my experience it's actually a red and white checkboard that underlays the "terrain detail" which sometimes peeks through. I had one instance where there was a half hex by 5 hex strip of it revealed and it was pretty obvious.

Comment: Well, it's on Steam so yes, it's always patched to the latest.  Interesting.

Comment: Steam just pulled another update for me today (10/28) and I'm still seeing this issue. Here's a screenshot... http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4831/redsplotchsm.png