# What is the significance of the red mark in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some tiles have red “chips” on them in Civilization 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/why-do-some-tiles-have-red-chips-on-them-in-civilization-5)

[image]

After playing many games of Civ 5, I have noticed the occurrence of strange red marks which appear on tiles occasionally. Upon closer inspection it seems to have a devil or bug-like aspect. I have conjectured that it could be:

**1)** Blood that has been shed in a skirmish

**2)** A developer's eccentric idea of an Easter Egg

**3)** A graphics card, driver or graphics rendering issue

**4)** A dark ritual performed my some primeval cult

Is there any significance to this feature or can we only speculate?

Answer (score 1):

It's a screwy graphics glitch.  Supposedly it was fixed in a patch, although their fix never quite worked for me.  I've never seen a fix for it that works for everybody, but the suggestions usually are:

- Try it in DX9 mode if you're playing in DX10/11, or vice versa.
- Change the graphics options, especially those that impact texture quality
- Update your graphics card drivers, if you can
- Growl in frustration and deal with it :(

I saw these all the time with my 8800GT, although I don't see them ever when I'm playing on my ATI-graphics-based notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen them on rock/ice tiles so I just figured they were lava, even if they looked a bit strange at first. [My Source](http://forums.2kgames.com).

Comment: Lava - lol. There is another theory.